# Offline Windows Install - How to view and change Pagefile settings

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, bsod, pagefile

I'm trying to fix a broken Windows 10 installation which I can't boot into (even into Safe Mode).  I have installed a fresh Windows 10 onto another hard drive.  How do I view and set the page file settings for the broken installation (i.e. without having access to the normal user interface)?

(I would like to check the pagefile settings as I am not seeing any memory dumps created when I get the blue screen error even though it seems to be taking a dump.)

Comment: You can't.  Why do you believe changing the page file will solve your problem?

Comment: @Ramhound it is possible. boot into the second Windows, run regedit.exe and mount the Registry from the offline Windows, change the settings and unmount the registry.

Comment: You can indeed do that

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, I'm trying to following the instructions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/bsod-finding-and-fixing-them/1939df35-283f-4830-a4dd-e95ee5d8669d) to find the memory dumps created when Windows crash during boot.  Part of the instructions relate to pagefile settings.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the registry path for that:

**Registry Key Name:**

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\

Value Name: PagingFiles

Type: REG_MULT_SZ

Data: C:\pagefile.sys 150 500
```

**Hive Location**

```
Windows\system32\config\system
```

**Dump setting**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl

CrashDumpEnabled REG_DWORD 0x0 = None
CrashDumpEnabled REG_DWORD 0x1 = Complete memory dump
CrashDumpEnabled REG_DWORD 0x2 = Kernel memory dump
CrashDumpEnabled REG_DWORD 0x3 = Small memory dump (64KB)
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin, for **PagingFiles** I have `?:\pagefile.sys`.  Should I change it to `C:\pagefile.sys`?

Comment: No; You should not.